# Linear regression to impute missing values pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression, categorical-data

I am trying to use linear regression approach with categorical variable.
Hence I believe it is best to use the dummy-based approach.
I know that there exists some missing values in the `delivery_cost` column of my dataset. Through is.null() I found that there are 17 values that are missing.

I know that the delivery cost linearly depends (in different ways for each branch of store i.e Sunshine, Footscray etc)

- the branches are already dummied through the store_id column, discrete variable
- dist_to_nearest_storehouse is a continuous variable
- seasons is a discrete variable ( hence the seasons Summer,Spring,Winter,Autumn will be treated as dummy)

I also need to be careful since isLoyaltyProgram ( 0 - not part of loyalty , 1 - part of loyalty ) the delivery_cost is discounted 10%

I was first wondering if using linear regression would be an correct approach to find the missing values.

I am currently using pandas to read the csv file which can be found in text file
https://paste.pythondiscord.com/raw/uvadaroyoj

If anybody could give me some guidance into the code behind I would love to read upon it.

Thank you.

Comment: Any help would be welcomed !

Comment: Feel free to comment so i can edit the question for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you are trying to predict the missing values based on other variables (dist_to_nearest_storehouse, season, isLoyaltyProgram). So what model you use depends on your data and your hypothesis: if you believe all the variables have a linear relationship with the y, then you could use linear regression, if not, you can use models that can fit non-linear data (SVM, decision-trees, neural-networks). But personally for 17 missing values, I would just drop them if they are not a big portion of my sample size.

Comment: yes this is correct i was wondering if I can use this 
https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/implementing-multiple-linear-regression-using-sklearn-43b3d3f2fe8b

Comment: Yup, I believe you can do that.

Comment: Since i know that isLoyaltyProgram determines whether or not to apply discount should I not include that in my features?

Comment: Sorry to rephrase my question ,
If a customer has loyalty, they get a 10% discount on delivery fee
^ I know that this is true, should I not include this in the features

Comment: I believe you should, because the feature "loyaltyprogram" affects delivery fee. If you believe they have a relationship, you should include that in your features.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting my answer, thanks.